# Default Network Policy in K8s

Tags: kubernetes, networking, traffic

I am really confused about Kubernetes default Network Policy. By accessing the official [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/), I can read that:

- By default, a pod is non-isolated for egress; all outbound connections are allowed
- By default, a pod is non-isolated for ingress; all inbound connections are allowed

Hence, `my understanding is all connections are allowed`. However, obviously that is not true. If, for example, creating a namespace and two pods inside it, it is not possible to communicate among each other unless you specify both `Ingress` and `Egress` Network policies.
***What do I miss?***

Comment: Did you create services for the pods?

Comment: Sure thing. I have 2 pods: client and server. Have created service for the server pod

Comment: It should be possible for them to communicate, no NetworkPolicy required. Where do you run you workloads? AWS, Azure, ...? Maybe they deploy something by default?

Comment: If that's the case is there any example I can see and run locally? Moreover, when do I need to apply Network Policy assuming we do not need it in the above case?

Comment: Deploy a local cluster (like `minikube`) and test it. But I never defined such policies and all worked (private clusters, gks, minikube ...).

Comment: ***However, obviously that is not true. If, for example, creating a namespace and two pods inside it, it is not possible to communicate among each other unless you specify both Ingress and Egress Network policies.*** -- This is not TRUE.

Answer (score 2):

You check the link [Default policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#default-policies)

By default, if no policies exist in a namespace, then all ingress and egress traffic is allowed to and from pods in that namespace.

You can create two pods with nginx image in a namespace.

```
kubectl run nginx1 --image=nginx --port=80
```

```
kubectl run nginx2 --image=nginx --port=80
```

check the pod ips

```
kubectl get pods -o wide
```

Run the curl command try to access

nginx1 to nginx2

```
kubectl exec -it nginx1 -- curl -I nginx2ip
```

Output:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.21.6
Date: Wed, 22 Jun 2022 13:42:57 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 615
Last-Modified: Tue, 25 Jan 2022 15:03:52 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "61f01158-267"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

nginx2 to nginx1

```
kubectl exec -it nginx2 -- curl -I nginx1ip
```

Output:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.21.6
Date: Wed, 22 Jun 2022 13:45:26 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 615
Last-Modified: Tue, 25 Jan 2022 15:03:52 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "61f01158-267"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Above both requests will get success responses